# Displaying text instead of icons for Likes/Reblogs on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tumblr

I need the Like and Reblog buttons to be displayed as text, like this:

> 3 hours ago / Like / Reblog / Permalink

This is what I'm currently using; the like and reblog buttons are displayed as icons:

```
{block:Posts}
    {block:Text}
        {Body}
    {/block:Text}
    {LikeButton} {ReblogButton}
{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: It would help if you had some code to show

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to style the Reblog button, but not the Like button; that's an iframe and can't be styled. Here's the result:

[image: 3 hours ago / Like icon / Reblog / Permalink]

Here's the code:

```
<style>
    .reblog_button {
        display: inline !important;
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .reblog_button:before {
        content: 'Reblog';
    }
    .reblog_button svg {
        display: none;
    }
    .like_button {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
{block:Posts}
    ... content here ...
   <div>{TimeAgo} / {LikeButton size=16} / {ReblogButton} / <a href="{Permalink}">Permalink</a></div>
{/block:Posts}
```